# Placing a function as a parameter within another function

Tags: javascript, function

I have the following code:

```
var doSomething = function(paramOne, paramTwo, fn){
    paramOne = paramOne + 3;
    paramOne = paramOne + 1;
    paramOne = paramOne * 8;

    return fn(paramOne, paramTwo);
};

function sum(paramOne, paramTwo){
    return paramOne + paramTwo;
};

var foo = doSomething(2, 2, sum);

alert(foo);
```

This code coming from a source I'm learning from...so it works fine.

I understand what's going on..kind of but I was hoping someone here could explain it?

The part I'm not understanding so well is why paramOne and paramTwo are in brackets on these two lines:

```
return fn(paramOne, paramTwo);
```

and

```
function sum(paramOne, paramTwo){
```

If someone could explain this to me it would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be getting confused because `paramOne` and `paramTwo` are used in different contexts.

Perhaps this would be clearer:

```
var doSomething = function(paramOne, paramTwo, fn){
    paramOne = paramOne + 3;
    paramOne = paramOne + 1;
    paramOne = paramOne * 8;

    return fn(paramOne, paramTwo);  // since `sum` is the function being passed in
                                    // below, the result here is the same as calling
                                    // sum(paramOne, paramTwo)
};

function sum(firstNumber, secondNumber){
    return firstNumber + secondNumber;
};

var foo = doSomething(2, 2, sum);

alert(foo);
```

As you can see here, the `sum` function's parameters are completely unrelated to the ones in `doSomething`. You have to pass values into `sum()` in order to give it values to add together and return.

Does that make more sense now?

Comment: Thanks JLRishe, that's a little more clear...I was confused that all the parameters were the same. So, by saying `return fn(paramOne, paramTwo);` .. gives `firstNumber` the value of `paramOne` and `secondNumber` the value of `paramTwo`? Otherwise I'm confused as to where `firstNumber` and `secondNumber` are defined. Thanks again!

Comment: @Forrest Yes, I would say your interpretation is correct.

Answer (score 0):

This line here: `return fn(paramOne, paramTwo);` consists of two parts: `return expression` and expression itself, which is a call to a function `fn` with two arguments `paramOne` and `paramTwo`.

This line: `function sum(paramOne, paramTwo){` is a definition of the function `sum`.

---

To better explain it we should start with this line: `var foo = doSomething(2, 2, sum);`. In this line we are calling a function `doSomething` and passing three arguments to it. First two arguments are two integer values: `2` and `2`, and the final argument is a function `sum`. In JavaScript you can pass functions as arguments to another functions by specifying it's name in the call.

When function `doSomething` is actually called all passed arguments are bound to local variables, specified in the definition of the function: `function(paramOne, paramTwo, fn)`. So `2` will become `paramOne`, the other `2` will become `paramTwo` and `sum` will become `fn`.

And when we call `fn()` later on we are actually calling `sum()`.

And the `sum` function here is pretty self explanatory.

If you have additional question just ask them in the comments to this answer. I will be glad to update my answer.

Comment: Thanks very much Slava. What I'm not understanding is why `fn()` and `sum()` both contain the same parameters? Why can't it simply be `return fn();` rather than `return fn(paramOne, paramTwo);`. Simply because if the function really being called is `sum()` then that already contains the parameters?

Comment: @Forrest: It has parameters declared, yes, but in the *call* you need to *pass* argument values.